# Android onHoverEvent and onTouchEvent

Tags: android

I have a class that is extending `View` and i want to use the stylus (galaxy note) for input as it has hovering capabilities.

I have added listeners for both hover and touch events but i have this issue i can not get around nicely: when i touch the screen with the stylus i have a hover event generated with `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT` and a touch event with `ACTION_DOWN`.

I would like to know if there is a way to know when i get an `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT` event if the stylus started to touch the screen or if it was moved away from it.

The same is when i lift the stylus but still in the hover zone: one `ACTION_UP` and one `ACTION_HOVER_ENTER`.

Comment: If it is such a bad question i would like to know what i did wrong so i could avoid doing that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is for Galaxy Note.**

On the `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT` event action i tryed several different things with no success:

1. event coordinates (getX, getY) - sometimes the coordinates when getting the stylus away from the screen were something like 0, -146 and the coordintes are both greater than 0 when the stylus starts touching the screen.
2. distance from the screen. There is an axis for the distance of the stylus tip from the screen. By checking if it enywhere near 0 the stylus tip should be touching the screen. Unfortunately the stylus device on the Galaxy note does not have this capability.
3. checking the pressure of the tip. This is still 0 when the hovering event with `ACTION_HOVER_EXIT` action is dispached.

Looking at the information stored in the device `device.toString()` i did not see anything different for the two cases. However, by using a `handler.postDelayed()` call i managed to get around this. Basically i do the exit hover actions after 10 ms and only if no touch event was dispached in the meantime.

Here is the output for my stylus for `device.toString()`:

```
Input Device 5: sec_e-pen
Keyboard Type: non-alphabetic
Key Character Map: /system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm
Sources: 0x2103 ( keyboard mouse )
AXIS_X: source=0x2002 min=0.0 max=799.8877 flat=0.0 fuzz=0.11234377
AXIS_Y: source=0x2002 min=0.0 max=1279.8877 flat=0.0 fuzz=0.11234969
AXIS_PRESSURE: source=0x2002 min=0.0 max=1.0 flat=0.0 fuzz=0.0
```